# Appium cannot install ipa file in simulator

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium, ipa

I am using appium 1.18.2 and here is my capabilities, so I tried to run automation script, and the error always failed to install the app:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platformVersion);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, platformName);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
cap.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.XCODE_ORG_ID, xcodeOrgId);
cap.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.XCODE_SIGNING_ID, xcodeSigningId);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/fendyridwan/Documents/Project/PSA/PSA-Automation-master/PSA-PASS-P2-iOS-Automation2/file/1602589286_Pilot_Audit_Sandbox__.ipa");
// Initialize driver
driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + appiumPort + "/wd/hub"), cap);
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

And here is the log of the error I got after running automation script.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/var/folders/pz/vbvlmv8j3s19l6_0lxckfr_r0000gp/T/2020914-51790-1lbtz5h.uu62/PSA-iOS-Audit.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'Potatos-Mac', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:43d:3389:bf74:843b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.6', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
    Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/var/folders/pz/vbvlmv8j3s19l6_0lxckfr_r0000gp/T/2020914-51790-1lbtz5h.uu62/PSA-iOS-Audit.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.
        at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
        at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:381:37)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'Potatos-Mac', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:43d:3389:bf74:843b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.6', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
    Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
        at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:95)
        at com.media2359.tests.BaseTest.initDriveriOS(BaseTest.java:177)
        at com.media2359.tests.BaseTest.setup(BaseTest.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/var/folders/pz/vbvlmv8j3s19l6_0lxckfr_r0000gp/T/2020914-51790-1lbtz5h.uu62/PSA-iOS-Audit.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'Potatos-Mac', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:43d:3389:bf74:843b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.6', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
    Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/var/folders/pz/vbvlmv8j3s19l6_0lxckfr_r0000gp/T/2020914-51790-1lbtz5h.uu62/PSA-iOS-Audit.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.
        at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
        at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:381:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
        ... 45 more
```

Any one know how to solve this problem?

Note: in real device I also cannot install ipa file using xcode or appium desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Let's clarify few things first:

For *real device* you must provide **.ipa** file.

For *simulator* you must provide **.app** file.

It is easier to go with simulator, just check [official docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest/). You can get rid of UDID, XCODE_ORG_ID and XCODE_SIGNING_ID. Make sure XCode supports simulator that you defined with **deviceName** and **platformVersion**.

If you want to try real device, it is quite different process and you definitely need to check official [manual](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/).

Make sure you have an active Apple developer account and have access to provision profile test application was signed. Use the same profile for WebDriverAgent signing as stated in documentation. Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

**.ipa file used in real device and .app file used in simulator.**

**.app** file can be found under 'Product' in file navigator or you can search it from derive data finder window.

and then use following capabilities for simulator in appium.

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "Simulator name",
  "noReset": true,
  "platformVersion": "PlateForm Version",
  "app": ".app file path",
  "automationName": "XCUITest"
}
```

find more information from [Real Device Setup](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-uiautomation/)